# SA disabled and no other user has access to master db

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, logins

I have inherited an old SQL Server 2008 R2 where SA login is disabled. No other logins gives access to master db, so I cannot really gain access to administrative stuff (create new logins, change login method etc). And at the same time, I cannot enable SA login either from SSMS.

How to proceed to gain control of this SQL instance?

Thanks.